# Best algorithm to sort linked list based patient's seriousness and arrival time?

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, linked-list

Let say a patient serious rank have 1, 2 and 3. What is the best efficient algorithm to sort the patients based on their seriousness and arrival time, if both patient have same seriousness, then arrival time is use to compare.

For example:

```
Patient name  Seriousness  Arrival time
Abby              3          7:01AM
Ally              3          7.08AM
Alicia            1          7.10AM
Abbygal           2          7.14AM
Annie             1          7.16AM
```

After sort get result like this:

```
Patient name  Seriousness  Arrival time
Alicia            1          7.10AM
Annie             1          7.16AM
Abbygal           2          7.14AM
Abby              3          7:01AM
Ally              3          7.08AM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort linked list, the most often used method is [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) because it is easy to implement with linked list and it's one of the best comparison-based sorting algorithm.

When you say *if both patient have same seriousness, then arrival time is use to compare.*, it means you need a [stable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability), and merge sort is stable, so give it a try.